# Doing calculations starting from the end of the data series in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Worksheet with dates and prices (each day has a price). Not all days from the calendar are there, so I don't use the workday function.

I created an if, that uses the IsInArray function to check if the date I want is in a DateArray, that I created with the first column.

I am trying to calculated monthly annualized returns using the formula:

```
(PriceEnd/PriceBegin)^(1/(number of days in the period/365.25))-1
```

Starting the from the last day (bottom of column), I get the date one year before with the DateAdd function (I make an if condition to see if it is there). Then I use the formula to calculate the value.

Move to one day before (penultimate day in the column), and repeat the process.

**Problem 1** When I do this, how can I organize my output, so that the last return of the last day (the first I calculated) is in the end of the output column?

**Problem 2** Considering that when I get near the top, the function that finds the date 1 year prior will not find any data. Is there any way to account for that directly?

The code I built so far:

```
Sub AnnualizedReturn()

Dim x As Long
Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateArray() As Variant
Dim FinalDate As Date, FirstDate As Date
Dim dAnRet As Date, dAnRet1 As Date, dAnRet2 As Date, dAnRet3 As Date, dAnRet4 As Date
Dim dAnRetpos As Long
Dim w As Workbook
Dim a As Long

Set w = ThisWorkbook

'find date limits
LastRow = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

DateArray() = Worksheets("TIME").Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value

FinalDate = w.Worksheets("TIME").Cells(LastRow, 1)
FirstDate = w.Worksheets("TIME").Cells(2, 1)

'clear the return worksheet and set format for dates
Worksheets("Ret").UsedRange.ClearContents

Worksheets("Ret").Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy;@"

'for each column (index), do all the procedures:
'copy dates to return output
For lRow = 2 To LastRow
    Worksheets("Ret").Cells(lRow, 1) = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(lRow, 1)
Next lRow


For lColumn = 2 To LastColumn
    If Worksheets("TIME").Cells(1, lColumn) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Ret").Cells(1, lColumn) = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(1, lColumn) & " Ret"

'calculate returns and output **********************
            For a = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            b = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(a, 1)

            dAnRet = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, b)
            dAnRet1 = DateAdd("d", 1, b)
            dAnRet2 = DateAdd("d", 2, b)
            dAnRet3 = DateAdd("d", 3, b)
            dAnRet4 = DateAdd("d", 4, b)

            If IsInArray2(dAnRet, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                dAnRetpos = IsInArray2(dAnRet, DateArray)
            ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet1, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
               dAnRetpos = IsInArray2(dAnRet1, DateArray)
            ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet2, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                dAnRetpos = IsInArray2(dAnRet2, DateArray)
            ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet3, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                dAnRetpos = IsInArray2(dAnRet3, DateArray)
            ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet4, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                dAnRetpos = IsInArray2(dAnRet4, DateArray)
            End If

 'added this part as the pasting procedure to output. This is giving the wrong result, the cell references are not correct, and problem 2 is not yet solved.

'if not enough data
        If dAnRetpos = "-1" Or dAnRetpos = 0 Then
            Worksheets("Ret").Cells(a, lColumn).Value = "Not Enough Data Available"
 'Return
        Else
            Worksheets("Ret").Cells(a, lColumn).Formula = "=('TIME'!" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & a & "/'TIME'!" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & dAnRetpos & ")^(1/((DAYS('TIME'!$A" & a & ",'TIME'!$A" & dAnRetpos & ")/365.25)))-1"

        End If

        Next a

    End If


Next lColumn



End Sub


Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(w.Worksheets("TIME SERIES").Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function


Public Function IsInArray2(DateToBeFound As Date, arr As Variant) As Long
Dim position As Long
'default return value if value not found in array
IsInArray2 = -1

For position = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(position, 1) = DateToBeFound Then
        IsInArray2 = position
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.
Obs. The code included here just contains the part referencing to the looping part. I removed the calculation part to keep it smaller and more readable.

Comment: Apparently, you already know about `Step -1` (`for a = LastRow to 2 step -1`), and I don't really see where do you build your "output"... So I don't see the question!^^ (My guess is that you don't use an array for your output and you should, in order to loop on it with `Step -1` when you "print" the results on the sheet!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The part I don't  know is how to output the data properly: I thought about, after I make the calculation, before the next step of the FOR, I paste the data to the same coordinate in a worksheet called Ret. Problem is I am not quite sure how to do that. Also, I don't know hot to account for the errors I get in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I got the right pasting procedure, so I will post here in case anyone needs it.

This is just the part of the code I modified, it pastes the date properly (iterating with a -1 step) and accounts for the missing data in the beginning.

For the missing dates, there is a block that adds another day (do the date 1 year before) until it finds a viable date (accounts for weekends and holidays).

**Code to be added:**

```
'calculate returns and output **********************
        For a = LastRow To 3 Step -1
            b = Worksheets("TIME").Cells(a, 1)

            c = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, b)

            dAnRet = DateAdd("d", 1, c)
            dAnRet1 = DateAdd("d", 1, dAnRet)
            dAnRet2 = DateAdd("d", 2, dAnRet)
            dAnRet3 = DateAdd("d", 3, dAnRet)
            dAnRet4 = DateAdd("d", 4, dAnRet)

            If dAnRet >= FirstDate Then

                If IsInArray2(dAnRet, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                    dAnRetPos = IsInArray2(dAnRet, DateArray)
                ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet1, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                    dAnRetPos = IsInArray2(dAnRet1, DateArray)
                ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet2, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                    dAnRetPos = IsInArray2(dAnRet2, DateArray)
                ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet3, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                    dAnRetPos = IsInArray2(dAnRet3, DateArray)
                ElseIf IsInArray2(dAnRet4, DateArray) <> "-1" Then
                    dAnRetPos = IsInArray2(dAnRet4, DateArray)
                End If

'if not enough data
                If dAnRetPos = "-1" Or dAnRetPos = 0 Then
                    Worksheets("Ret").Cells(a, lColumn) = "Not Enough Data Available"
'3Y Return
                Else
                    Worksheets("Ret").Cells(a, lColumn).Formula = "=('TIME'!" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & a & "/'TIME'!" & Col_Letter(lColumn) & dAnRetPos & ")^(1/((DAYS('TIME'!$A" & a & ",'TIME'!$A" & dAnRetPos & ")/365.25)))-1"

                End If

                Else
                    Worksheets("Ret").Cells(a, lColumn) = "Not Enough Data Available"

            End If
        dAnRetPos = 0
        Next a

    End If

Next lColumn
```

All the new variables are declared as Long.